# Xamarin.Forms styling

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I develop Xamarin.Forms app (latest version of Xamarin), I'm targeting only Android. I use TabbedPage which displays bar on the top of the screen. I want to make my custom visual item that will look like the TabbedPage bar. Where can I find out font size, font type, background color, margins etc so I can make my custom visual item that will look like TabbedPage bar?

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you want to create tabbed page I think you should use Xamarin.forms controls (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page/). But if you want to create custom tabbed then you have to use custom renderer for top navigation bar.